# Slick 3.0 Logging Query Performance

Tags: slick, slick-3.0

Currently I have enabled DEBUG logging on:

```
slick.backend
```

It logs the transaction start/end, compiled sql query being run by slick, and success/results.

Can slick provide me information about query running time? Which package should I enable DEBUG mode on, to get this information?

---

**Edit**:

I found this [link](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/scalaquery/log/scalaquery/Wmlku0ATwUg/RRoCV67LoE8J) which talks about this not being possible. Does this still hold true?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Found answer to the question with help of @szeiger. Enable logging on the following package to get timing information on execution of SQL queries in Slick 3.0:

```
slick.jdbc.JdbcBackend.benchmark
```

Other useful packages to enable DEBUG logging on:

```
slick.jdbc.JdbcBackend.statement
slick.jdbc.StatementInvoker.result
slick.compiler.QueryCompilerBenchmark

*Reference:*
https://github.com/slick/slick/blob/master/common-test-resources/logback.xml
```